# How to fix this after command sudo apt-get upgrade

Tags: command-line

```
uugana@Hunnu:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up icedtea-netx:i386 (1.5.1-1ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/itweb-settings because link group itweb-settings is broken
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /usr/share/man/man1/itweb-settings.1.gz with a link
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/itweb-settings doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package icedtea-netx:i386 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icedtea-7-plugin:i386:
 icedtea-7-plugin:i386 depends on icedtea-netx (= 1.5.1-1ubuntu1); however:
  Package icedtea-netx:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package icedtea-7-plugin:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 icedtea-netx:i386
 icedtea-7-plugin:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to install icedtea plugin on Utopic Unicorn 14.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/541132/unable-to-install-icedtea-plugin-on-utopic-unicorn-14-10)

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-broken --fix-missing`